# PDF/SVG and adobe illustrator compatibility

Tags: matplotlib, pdf, adobe-illustrator

When matplotlib plot with confidence bands is exported to SVG or PDF and opened in Adobe illustrator for editing, the bands are getting corrupted:

Original plot in matplotlib (the PDF and SVG open fine in a pdf reader / inkscape):

[image: Original plotted in matplotlib]

SVG export then converted to PDF in inkscape, and opened Adobe Illustrator:

[image: SVG export opened in Adobe Illustrator]

Figure saved as PDF using matplotlib and then opened in Adobe Illustrator:

[image: PDF export opened in Adobe Illustrator]

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Looks like only the stroke/fills are different. What happens if you overlap each figure in illustrator and view in artwork mode?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad stroke gets picked up by illustrator correctly. So only plotting the upper and lower confidence lines avoiding the fill between them works. After that we had to put the fill in Illustrator.

Comment: Could be relevant: https://jonathansoma.com/lede/data-studio/matplotlib/exporting-from-matplotlib-to-open-in-adobe-illustrator/